# what is the difference between virus, worm, trojan and other malware

Tags: attacks, malware

Looking through the questions in IT security, I found out that there is no answer which cover this question in depth.

I am aware of the answer and just hope to see something detailed about:

- main differences
- tendencies in work
- purpose
- how to protect
- how it is duplicating

Comment: I don't know why anyone cares about the VWT designation anymore. It's for the most part a moot point as most of the powerful threats released now are a hybrid of all three, often served off of infection servers that are able to probe the OS, installed services, and versions of plugins/browser objects; immediately calculating the top most usable vulnerabilities that particular machine has. Also, what comes in is better termed to be a loader which then phones home to determine the VWT package needed to be delivered. Arguing whether it's a Virus, Worm or Trojan is often rather a moot point.

Comment: You seem to have put a remarkably small amount of effort into looking up something which has an abundant amount of information available on the first page of a Google search.

Comment: @JulesMazur most probably you have not even put an effort to read the question. It was mentioned there that I know the answer and posting the question only because I think it will be beneficial to have such post on IT security.

Comment: Salvador - I don't think this question really has much meaning any more. The terminology exists and is easily googled, but it doesn't add anything to a security professional. These titles don't form part of a defence plan, instead you implement controls on the possible activities and channels. Closed as NC.

Answer (score 3):

These days most threats do not fall into any single of these categories, almost all will fall into more than one. These are called "blended threats" or more often simply just malware. It's rare that you see malware that only can replicate itself in one way, that's why malware is such a problem.

To be honest these terms don't mean much anymore, as there are many threats out there that don't fall into any of these categories, or more than one of these categories. You have to expect that malware will have several methods of spread. Malware may first be run by an unsuspecting user opening a PDF file from an email, but then spread to other systems over the network and USB sticks. Or it may arrive in a USB stick and spread itself by emailing a PDF to all known contacts.